# Cypress get specific text

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have this element

```
<label for="prod-field">Project
  <span class="aui-icon">Required</span>
</label>
```

I want to check if Label text is equal to Project

```
cy.get('[for="prod-field"]').should('have.text', 'Project')
```

but the result is

```
-'ProjectRequired'
  +'Project'
```

so this selector take also span...

How can i select them independently and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```js
cy.get('[for="prod-field"]').should(($el) => {
  expect(
    $el
      .contents() // Grab all contents
      .first() // The text node you're looking for
      .text() // Get the text
      .trim() // And trim the white space
  ).to.eq('Project');
});
```

As you can see in the above, we can do this, however the selector is over complicated. I'd recommend you to tweak the HTML a bit if you can to something like:

```html
<label for="prod-field"
  ><span class="label-text">Project</span>>
  <span class="aui-icon">Required</span>
</label>
```

Then, you can simply do this:

```js
cy.get('[for="prod-field"] .label-text').should('have.text', 'Project');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your locator selects label and all within it, just change the locator to the span like this:

```
 cy.get('[for="prod-field"] span.label-text').should('have.text', 'Project')
```

Comment: but how to check only label?